# Unable to communicate with SPI based display board

Tags: spi, embedded, communication, display, debugging

I need to communicate with a display board that is acting as master and my board will act as slave.
The reference document says that

"
Totally 26 bytes for communication between display and control card

Byte0 to Byte5 are for temp value.

Byte6 to Byte13 for LED information (0: off, 1:on).

Byte14 is command from control card to display.

Byte15 is command from display to control card.

Byte16 is Display ID.

Byte17 is Display software revision number.

Byte18 is Display software version number.

Byte19 to Byte25 Reserved for Future Use.

"

And about frame protocol it says

"
SPI interface is used for communication. The DISPLAY is spi master and the control board is spi slave. There is a communication protocol. Maxim-Dallas crc8(parameter model = x8+x5+x4+1) is used for checksum. To start communication, 0xAA is sent at the beginning. CHECKSUM INCLUDES START BYTE AS 0XAA.Display send data for every 20ms
Display card has the individual MCU and communicates with Control Card via SPI interface that consists of MOSI, MISO, SS and CLK signals."

[image]

Now when I checked using logic analyser display board is sending two type of data packets alternatively. read packet and write packet.

Here are the screenshots of write packet.
[image: Write packet from display board]

and here is the read packet from board
[image]

Now I want to send data to display board to change values of its first fifteen bytes.
Please guide how should I send data on MISO. as the length of data and clock cycles are being controlled by Display card.
Here is the code i am using for receiving data and at the end sending my data buffer.
But you can see that it is not producing desired output on MISO pin.
Can you guide how should i change my code to send data in desired format.
thanks in advance

```
for (;;)
{

    
    failed = 0;
    PT_WAIT_UNTIL_W_PERIOD((devComReceive(consts->spi, preamble, 1) == 1), 10);

    if (preamble[0] == 0xAA)
    {
        receiveddata[0] = preamble[0];
        //PT_WAIT_UNTIL_W_PERIOD((devComReceive(consts->spi, &receiveddata[1], 24) == 24),  10); 
        failed=0;


      PT_WAIT_UNTIL_W_PERIOD((devComReceive(consts->spi, &receiveddata[1], 1) == 1),  10);          //Command Byte
        
        PT_WAIT_UNTIL_W_PERIOD((devComReceive(consts->spi, &receiveddata[2], 1) == 1),  10);          //Address Byte
        
          PT_WAIT_UNTIL_W_PERIOD((devComReceive(consts->spi, &receiveddata[3], 1) == 1),  10);          //Data Size Byte
          
          
              if(receiveddata[3] <= 20 && receiveddata[3] > 0)
              {
       
                  PT_WAIT_UNTIL_W_PERIOD((devComReceive(consts->spi, &receiveddata[4], receiveddata[3]) == receiveddata[3]),  10);          //Data Bytes
                      
                      PT_WAIT_UNTIL_W_PERIOD((devComReceive(consts->spi, &receiveddata[25], 1) == 1),  10);         //Checksum Byte
                      
                      datalength = ( receiveddata[3] + 4 );
                      checkingCRC=crc8MaximArray(crc8MaximInit(), receiveddata, datalength);

                      if (checkingCRC!=receiveddata[25])
                      {
                        failed = 1;
                        failedcounter++;
                      }
                      else
                      {
                        failed = 0;
                        successcounter++;
                      }
                  
              }
              


                  
    }
    params->buffer[0]=0xAA;
    params->buffer[1]=0x01;
    params->buffer[2]=2;
    params->buffer[3]=1;
    params->buffer[4]=0xFF;
    params->buffer[5]=crc8MaximArray(crc8MaximInit(), params->buffer, 5);

   devComSend(consts->spi, params->buffer, 6);
    
}
```

Comment: As I understand this protocol you have to provide your output content during reception (during the 10 dummy zeros here), not in a separate frame later.

Comment: I have just checked that data on MISO line keep comming even I halt my controller on debug. Couldn't figure out where this data is comming. Any comment on that?

Comment: As SPI slave you don't have control over the transfer, there is no way to pause the master clock. Your SPI hardware interface will transmit whatever is in the internal shift register at the moment the master clocks it out.

Comment: But the data put by devComSend() is no where to be seen. It is true that as a slave controller does not have control over clock. but I am getting same data on MISO pin. Either i put some data byte by byte afre each receiving, at the end or even pause the controller in debug. Data is same on MISO line.

Comment: Can you please provide the document from where you extracted the SPI protocol?